# Is it possible to update a nested array with obj

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create an ingridients component. basically, user would input the qty, measurement and name then when they press the add button, it should show up at the top with a bulletin or just a paragraph but im unable to figure out this nested state thing. please help. i been stuck on this for 2 weeks

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AddRecipe extends Component {
  state = {
    Ingredients: [{ name: "", qty: "", measurement: "" }],
  };

  handleIngredientChange = (event, index, field) => {
    const newIngredient = [...this.state.ingredients];
    newIngredient[index][field] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ Ingredients: newIngredient });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("state:: > ", this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.Ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
          <>
            <p>
              {ingredient.name} + {ingredient.qty} + {ingredient.measurement}
            </p>
          </>
        ))}
        {this.state.Ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Street number"
              value={ingredient.qty}
            />
            <input type="text" placeholder="City" value={ingredient.name} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="State" value={ingredient.measurement} />
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Submit"
              onChange={(event) =>
                this.handleAddressChange(event, index, "state")
              }
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AddRecipe;
```

Comment: I am still not clear on what you need, but you can read about [working with array](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays) in React

Answer (score 0):

you could by using spread operator:

`... this.setState({ Ingredients: {...newIngredient, PROPERTIE:NEWVALUE }); ...`